# I am having trouble with the code below. It is saying 'results' is an expression type '?'. which is not a collection type

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, linq, inner-join

I am having trouble with the code below. It is saying 'results' is an expression type '?'. which is not a collection type. And also my "=" sign between CInt(table1(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)) = CInt(table2(ComboBox2.SelectedItem)) is saying 'Equals' expected. Any help would be great, thanks! Not sure if table1 and table2 is the correct syntax either...

```
Dim tt As New DataTable()
tt = DtSet1.Tables(0)

Dim rr As New DataTable()
rr = DtSet2.Tables(0)

Dim DTA As New DataTable()
DTA.Columns.Add("Account", GetType(Integer))
DTA.Columns.Add("First", GetType(String))
DTA.Columns.Add("Last", GetType(String))
DTA.Columns.Add("Code", GetType(String))

Dim DTB As New DataTable()
DTB.Columns.Add("Code", GetType(String))
DTB.Columns.Add("Amount", GetType(Integer))

For g As Integer = 1 To 6
    Dim row As DataRow = DTA.NewRow()
    row("Account") = g
    row("First") = 10 + g
    row("Last") = 20 + g
    row("Code") = 30 + g
    DTA.Rows.Add(row)

    row = DTB.NewRow()
    row("Code") = 40 + g
    row("Amount") = 50 + g
    DTB.Rows.Add(row)
Next

Dim results = _
    From table1 In DTA.AsEnumerable() Join table2 In DTB.AsEnumerable() _
        On CInt(table1(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)) = CInt(table2(ComboBox2.SelectedItem)) _
    New With { _
        Key .Account = CInt(tt("Account")), _
        Key .First = CInt(tt("First")), _
        Key .Last = CInt(tt("Last")), _
        Key .Offer = CInt(tt("Code")), _
        Key .Amount = CInt(rr("Amount")) _
    }

For Each item As var In results
    Console.WriteLine([String].Format("Account = {0}, First = {1}, Last = {2}, Code = {3}, Amount = {4}", item.Account, item.First, item.Last, item.Code, item.Amount))
Next

Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: For the "Equals() expected" problem, I would imagine you could simply substitute `Equals()` for the `=`.  I'm not familiar enough with VB syntax to help you solve the other problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that worked! But not "var" is saying 'Type var is not defined' what should I define this as?

Comment: Are you using [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx)?

Comment: @Chrisetiquette Does it work if you take out the `As var`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton it does not, it then underlines all my items. There is another issue i just spotted as well: New With read 'End of statement expected'

Comment: @Chrisetiquette What is the intent of the code with respect to the ComboBoxes?

Comment: @AndrewMorton The comboBoxes selecet the field in the data that the two lists share in common, its what they're being matched together with.

Comment: @Chrisetiquette And what is the relationship of the *columns* of `tt` with the query? Did you intend to select a particular *row*? Are you using `Option Strict On`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton tt and rr are the two dataTables in which i want to combine. I did not intend to select a particular row, I am not entirely sure on how to accomplish what I want. I dont believe i am using option strict on...

Comment: @Chrisetiquette 1) It is not clear to me where `DTA` and `DTB` come in to selecting items from a join on `tt` and `rr`. If `tt` and `rr` happen to come from a database (e.g. Access, SQL Server...) it would be simpler to construct an SQL query to do the join. 3) I strongly recommend that you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) and set it as the default for all VB projects.

Comment: @AndrewMorton 1) tt and rr are two data tables i created and populated using data set fill.

Comment: @Chrisetiquette OK, where did you populate them from? Was it a database? It would help if you could edit your question to give details like that: it is better to give all the information that you think we might need instead of us having to ask questions about every detail.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Im pulling the data form two excel files into two DataSets then putting them into DataTables. I have two comboBoxes on my form that when i select each excel file it populates each comboBox with the excel files header names. This is where I select the code to match them to each other.

Comment: You're missing the keyword `Select` before `New`.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code doesn't compile - are you sure the actual version is the same?

Here it goes. The LINQ syntax is wrong. First off, in the `Join` clause you **MUST** use `Equals` keyword, not the `=` sign. Next the `CInt()` function is misplaced - it should be applied to the `ComboBox1.SelectedItem` in order to produce an integer, which will be treated as a column index. Finally you need to use the `Select` keyword to specify the select clause. Just before the `New` keyword. As a result you'll get an `IEnumerable(Of <anonymous type>)` in the `results` variable.

Later in the `For ... Next` loop declaration, loose the "As var". The `item` type will be inferred from the usage.

Plain LINQ queries are difficult. They require both practice and theoretical knowledge in order to be mastered. Fortunately there are LINQ extension methods. They achieve essentially the same, but in a different manner. If they are executed sequentially, the code becomes more readable and closes up toward the imperative approach.

E.g. the above LINQ query could be rewritten as follows:

```
Dim results = DTA.AsEnumerable().Join(DTB.AsEnumerable(), 
        Function(r1) r1(CInt(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)), ' The key selector for the LEFT row
        Function(r2) r2(CInt(ComboBox2.SelectedItem)), ' The key selector for the RIGHT row
        Function(tt, rr) New With { 
            Key .Account = CInt(tt("Account")), _
            Key .First = CInt(tt("First")), _
            Key .Last = CInt(tt("Last")), _
            Key .Offer = CInt(tt("Code")), _
            Key .Amount = CInt(rr("Amount")) _
        } ' Result selector
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague with regard to where the data comes from.

I have made an example with two ComboBoxes and a Button on a form; it creates its own sample data:

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1

    ' a method to show a datatable
    Sub PrintDataTable(dt As DataTable)
        Dim columnWidth = 10
        Dim separator = New String("="c, columnWidth * dt.Columns.Count)
        Console.WriteLine(separator)
        Console.WriteLine(dt.TableName)

        For Each n As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            Console.Write(n.ColumnName.PadLeft(columnWidth))
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()

        For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
            For i = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                Console.Write(r.Item(i).ToString().PadLeft(columnWidth, " "c))
            Next
            Console.WriteLine()
        Next
        Console.WriteLine(separator)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' create some test data
        Dim DTA As New DataTable("DTA")
        DTA.Columns.Add("Account", GetType(Integer))
        DTA.Columns.Add("First", GetType(String))
        DTA.Columns.Add("Last", GetType(String))
        DTA.Columns.Add("Code", GetType(String))

        Dim DTB As New DataTable("DTB")
        DTB.Columns.Add("Code", GetType(String))
        DTB.Columns.Add("Amount", GetType(Integer))

        ' add values of test data where some values of "Code" are equal
        For g As Integer = 1 To 6
            Dim row As DataRow = DTA.NewRow()
            row("Account") = g
            row("First") = (10 + g).ToString()
            row("Last") = (20 + g).ToString()
            row("Code") = (30 + g).ToString()
            DTA.Rows.Add(row)

            row = DTB.NewRow()
            row("Code") = (30 + CInt(g Mod 4)).ToString()
            row("Amount") = (50 + g).ToString()
            DTB.Rows.Add(row)
        Next

        ' show the data for visual verification
        PrintDataTable(DTA)
        PrintDataTable(DTB)

        ' N.B. for the test data it is necessary to select "Code" in each ComboBox
        Dim colToMatchA = CStr(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
        Dim colToMatchB = CStr(ComboBox2.SelectedItem)

        Console.WriteLine($"A: {colToMatchA} B: {colToMatchB}")

        ' N.B. it is required that the column data have a .ToString() method which is
        ' unique for each possible value. Note that the number 0 will match the string "0" etc.
        Dim result = From a In DTA
                     Join b In DTB
                     On a.Item(colToMatchA).ToString() Equals b.Item(colToMatchB).ToString()
                     Select New With {.Account = a("Account"), .CodeA = a("Code"), .Amount = b("Amount")}

        For Each r In result
            Console.WriteLine(r.ToString())
        Next

        Console.WriteLine("Done.")

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim colsA = {"Account", "First", "Last", "Code"}
        Dim colsB = {"Code", "Amount"}
        ComboBox1.DataSource = colsA
        ComboBox2.DataSource = colsB

    End Sub

End Class
```

If you select "Code" in both Comboboxes, it gives this output:

```
========================================
DTA
   Account     First      Last      Code
         1        11        21        31
         2        12        22        32
         3        13        23        33
         4        14        24        34
         5        15        25        35
         6        16        26        36
========================================
====================
DTB
      Code    Amount
        31        51
        32        52
        33        53
        30        54
        31        55
        32        56
====================
A: Code B: Code
{ Account = 1, CodeA = 31, Amount = 51 }
{ Account = 1, CodeA = 31, Amount = 55 }
{ Account = 2, CodeA = 32, Amount = 52 }
{ Account = 2, CodeA = 32, Amount = 56 }
{ Account = 3, CodeA = 33, Amount = 53 }
Done.
```